# How to get multi dymentional array value dynamically in php?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

```
function test_theme_get_post_meta() {
$post_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'test_options', true); // this will return multi dymentional array
$func_args = func_get_args(); // to get func argument
switch (func_num_args()) {
    case 1:   
        if(isset($post_meta[$func_args[0]])) {
           return $post_meta[$func_args[0]];
        }                
        break;

    case 2:                
        if(isset($post_meta[$func_args[0]][$func_args[1]])) {
           return $post_meta[$func_args[0]][$func_args[1]];
        }
        break;

    case 3:                
        if(isset($post_meta[$func_args[0]][$func_args[1]][$func_args[2]])) {
           return $post_meta[$func_args[0]][$func_args[1]][$func_args[2]];
        }
        break;
} }
```

test_theme_get_post_meta('one_dymention_id', 'two_dymention_id');

Hello,
I wanna create a dynamic function in php. But I can't. 
My question is: I have a multi dymentional array, I want get those value dynamically by function.

Like if I pass one argument in test_theme_get_post_meta() funciton it return first dymention value, if I pass two arguments it will pass second dymention value. Thus I wanna get unlimited dymention value.

I don't want to create case 1,2,3,4 etc. I want it auto.

If anyone know the solution please help me.

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you were hoping?:

```
function test_theme_get_post_meta() {
  $result = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'test_options', true); // this will return multi dymentional array
  foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
    if (isset($result[$arg])) {
      $result = $result[$arg];
    }
    else {
      // might want to throw exception or return null if not found
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) for your great and easier solution